# Getting Error String was not recognized as a valid boolean when using Ajax CollapsiblePanelExtender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

First, let me explain the scenario.

In my ASP.Net application, i am using a AJAX collapsiblepanelextender inside a repeater. As the repeater doesn't have inbuilt paging so, I implemented paging using paged datasource. But, there was a requirement from client to use client-side pagination where the page must not postback when the page is changed for repeater. So, I have used a jquery based script for this client side pagination.

Client side paging is working fine. And when the page is loaded for the first time, collapsiblepanel also works. But when I go to some other page, and then click to expand collapsiblepanel, it throws an error "String was not recognized as a valid boolean".

I am not getting, where is the issue.

Comment: I think I am the first one to get such an issue.. :)